# Access Object variable in Script Component in SSIS 2012

Tags: c#, ssis, ssis-2012

I am using SSIS in VS 2012, and a lot of the answers I'm finding appear to be working for older or newer versions.

I have declared a ReadWriteVariables called User::Weather_XML
[image: Script Transformation Editor]
(I hope this displays - my company policy doesn't allow access to imgur, so it looks like it works, but I can't tell.)

I've looked at a lot of answers:
[Reading object variable values in SSIS script component source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011550/reading-object-variable-values-in-ssis-script-component-source) - this refers to Dts.Variables, which apparently is no longer available in 2012?

So my code has this, but it won't compile because Dts.Variables doesn't exist in the current context:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    oleda.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables("Weather_XML").Value);
```

How do I get the set of data into the Script Component so I can use it?

I have a data set, with an URL string - I want to go through the list and use each URL, get the corresponding XML, and then save that back to my object.  Or write it to a database, or something.  It seems like it's just the syntax, but I can't figure it out.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450289/how-to-access-ssis-package-variables-inside-script-component) uses a IDTSVariables100, but then references it to a string, and I have an entire object, with strings within it.  If I add the code

```
    IDTSVariables100 varCollection = null;
    this.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::Weather_XML");
```

it does compile, so it's progress.

I am very weak in C#.  Obviously.  What is the syntax needed in 2012 to get the Object variable into something I can use in the Script Component?  With, perhaps some guidance on accessing a specific part of the object.  Pretend that the URL is the first string field in the object, and I currently have 4 rows.

Also, I include the following namespaces, probably way more than I need:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

Answer (score 2):

In SSIS, the *Script Task* and the *Script Component* are similar but definitely not identical.

When using the *Script Component* `Dts.Variables` **is not available** (although in *Script Task* it is available).

The following MSDN article compares *Script Task* and *Script Component* clarifying the differences between them: [Comparing Script Task and Script Compnent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/comparing-the-script-task-and-the-script-component?view=sql-server-2017)

The relevant info from that article is as follows:

> **Using variables**
>
> The Script component uses typed accessor properties of the
>   autogenerated based class, created from the component's
>   ReadOnlyVariables and ReadWriteVariables properties. For example:
>
> [Visual Basic]
>
> ```
> Dim myVar as String 
> myVar = Me.Variables.MyStringVariable
> ```
>
> [C#]
>
> ```
> string myVar; 
> myVar = this.Variables.MyStringVariable;
> ```

In your case the following syntax should work:

```
var xml = this.Variables.Weather_XML;
```

The following TechNet article is another good source with examples of using Variables in the SSIS *Script Component*.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22198.use-ssis-variables-and-parameters-in-a-script-component.aspx

Comment: Well explained!

Comment: Why 'var xml'? It's an object, but I have to pull out a URL/string.  Does this need to go in the PreExecute method?  Even there, I get the error "'Variables' does not contain a definition for 'Weather_XML' and no extension method 'Weather_XML' accepting a first argument of type 'Variables' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I just created a new SSIS project, added a dummy DataFlow task with an Excel file as input to satisfy the designer tool and get it to allow me to add a Script Component.  I then added a Package level string variable called `Weather_XML` (represented in GUI as `User::Weather_XML`, then I edited the Script Component adding `Weather_XML` as a ReadWriteVariable.  Then I chose 'Edit Script` to get the template C# code -- I was able to reference `this.Variables.Weather_XML` in any of the methods in the template: `PreExecute()` `PostExecute()` `CreateNewOutoutRows()`.

Comment: Maybe I'll start a fresh project.  Maybe there's so many tries in this one that it's just messed up.

Comment: A fresh project, just adding that one line, and it gives an error.  Am I missing a directive or assembly reference?  Does this work in 2012?

Comment: I did not have to add any additional assemblies or `using` statements etc.  I do not have VS2012 installed -- sorry.  When I choose 'Edit Script` from the Script Component properties dialog, what happens is this: long wait, then another instance of VS opens with just the C# code.  I am curious if you see similar behavior?

Comment: Yes, that is the same.  And I selected a Source Script Component, as did you, since there is a CreateNewOutputRows() method in the template.  So perhaps it's the ancient version I have.

Comment: I can access a string, using your code above.  But not an object.  I'm now working to modify my code so one record at a time is used, with strings, and skipping the object altogether.